# Jquery validation check if value in array show error as per show jquery error message

Tags: jquery, validation

```
var city = ["Cleveland", "Gilberdyke", "Llanrwst", "Swadlincote", "Turriff", "Westhill", "Oban", "Craigavon"]

$(".submitform").validate({
  rules: {
         state: {
            required: true,
         },
         country: {
            required: true,
         },
         city: {
           required: true,     
         },
     },
});
```

*i want to check if input city value* **in in city array** *so display validation message* **This city are already exist**

i am using validation script as per below

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

**I want to display message like**

[image]

Please help !!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) you create a [custom validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/) `array` here for example:

```
$.validator.addMethod(
  "array",
   function(value, element, array) {
          return !array.includes(value);
   },"erreur"
);
```

(2) you use it with your array `city`:

```
$(".submitform").validate({
  rules: {
         state: {
            required: true,
         },
         country: {
            required: true,
         },
         city: {
           required: true,
           "array": city     
         },
     },
});
```